# How to prevent re-rendering of random colours in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, colors

I've assigned a random colour to three image icons upon rendering. However when I click a button to render a dialog popup, the colours of the icons get re-rendered again. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
const colours = [blue[800], green[800], lime[500], brown[500], 
grey[500], yellow[800], blueGrey[500],
orange[800], purple[800], red[800], pink[800], indigo[800], cyan[500], teal[500],];
const colour = () =>  colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)];
```

```
handleClick= () => {
    this.setState({
        openDialog: true
    }); 
}
```

```
render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}  variant="contained" >
        Post
        </Button> 

        <Avatar  style={{backgroundColor: colour()}}>S</Avatar>
        <Avatar  style={{backgroundColor: colour()}}>S</Avatar>
        <Avatar  style={{backgroundColor: colour()}}>S</Avatar>

        <Dialog
        keepMounted
        fullWidth = "true"
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={this.state.openDialog}
        >
        </Dialog>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bouman-8p2zb

Comment: You can use PureComponent to prevent the rerendering component. Also, you can use the react hook with separate UseState for color and `openDialog` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rerendering because you are changing the component's state with `openDialog` state. Maybe you can store the calculated colors in the state as well but the component itself will be rerendered again. At the end it should show the same already calculated colors.

Maybe generate the colors in the `constructor` then store it in the `state`:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    openDialog: false,
    colors: [
      colour(),
      colour(),
      colour()
    ]
  };
}
```

Then use somehow this:

```
<Avatar  style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[0]}}>S</Avatar>
<Avatar  style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[1]}}>S</Avatar>
<Avatar  style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[2]}}>S</Avatar>
```

Additionally you need to change the `handleClick` as well:

```
handleOpenDialog = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    openDialog: true
  }));
};
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want those colors to update in every rerender, just move the color() function out of the render function.

You can declare the colors as the `state` in the constructor function and use it as the value of the background color of buttons.

And update the state in the situation you want.

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-margulis-uc610?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark